# Lifetime issue when wrapping a function returning an Iterator

Tags: rust, iterator, traits, lifetime

I am building a custom data structure which supposes to return an iterator for its elements. If simplified, it can look like this:

```rust
use std::iter::{Iterator, StepBy};

// My collection which returns iterator to it's elements
pub trait MyCollection<'a, T: 'a> {
  type I: Iterator<Item = &'a T>;
  fn find_something(&'a self) -> Self::I;
}
```

Now, in some cases, I would like to create a "wrapper" for this collection that transforms the elements returned by the iterator. For the sake of this example let's assume that this wrapper allows skipping over some elements of the original iterator:

```rust
// Wrapper for a collection that allows iterating over elements with a step
pub struct StepWrapper<'a, A>(&'a A, usize);

impl<'a, T: 'a, A: MyCollection<'a, T>> MyCollection<'a, T> for StepWrapper<'a, A> {
  type I = StepBy<A::I>;
  fn find_something(&'a self) -> Self::I {
    self.0.find_something().step_by(self.1)
  }
}

// Function which takes a collection and a step value and returns a wrapped collection
fn wrap<'a, T: 'a, A: MyCollection<'a, T>>(a: &'a A, step: usize) -> impl MyCollection<'a, T> {
  StepWrapper(a, step)
}
```

Unfortunately, I get a compilation error when trying to use this code:

```rust
// Example
impl<'a> MyCollection<'a, u64> for Vec<u64> {
  type I = std::slice::Iter<'a, u64>;
  fn find_something(&'a self) -> Self::I {
    return self.iter();
  }
}

fn main() {
  let collection = vec![12, 13, 14];
  let wrapped = wrap(&collection, 2);
  
  // Error now
  let result = wrapped.find_something().skip(1).next();
  //           ^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough

  println!("{}", result.unwrap());
}
```

I understand that `StepWrapper<'a, A>::find_something` requires `self` to be borrowed for the same lifetime as the original collection. But all my attempts to decouple lifetimes of a collection and a wrapper were unuseful. Essentially a `find_something` function in the wrapper needs to return a result which outlives itself. Is there a way to express it in Rust?

Comment: Fixed the code. 
When I remove lifetime `'a` from the `self` I get an error in `impl<'a> MyCollection<'a, u64> for Vec<u64>`.

Comment: In Rust it's easier to wrap not a reference, but the whole object (by value), thus eliminating all the pain of dealing with references. If you ever need to get to the inner value, you can implement such a method that unwraps it (by reference or by value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you're using is called a *streaming iterator*, and unfortunately it's not possible with the `Iterator` trait.

This is a current weakness of Rust's type system: it lacks what are known as generic associated types, or GATs. There's an [RFC for this language feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1598-generic_associated_types.md) and a [tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44265).

In the meantime, the [`streaming_iterator` crate](https://docs.rs/streaming-iterator/0.1.5/streaming_iterator/) is designed to provide the functionality you're looking for.